# QStyledItemDelegate's sizeHint method not called for a QTableView row

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I have [QTableView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtableview.html) using a [QSqlQueryModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqlquerymodel.html) (it fetches data from SQLite).

There is a [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstyleditemdelegate.html) subclass called `MiniItemDelegate` that I use as a delegate for the items.  I set up a [sizeHint()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) method like this:

```
QSize MiniItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                 const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // just for testing...breakpoint shows this line never gets called
    return QSize(256,256);  
}
```

I'm not sure why this method isn't called when I run the following code:

```
m_pMiniItemDelegate = new MiniItemDelegate(this);
ui->PList_tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->PList_tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->PList_tableView->setItemDelegate(m_pMiniItemDelegate);
ui->PList_tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
ui->PList_tableView->setModel(ListMiniSqlModel::instance());
```

This also doesn't work:

```
ui->PList_tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui->PList_tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
```

Nor does this:

```
QHeaderView* headerView = ui->PList_tableView->horizontalHeader();
headerView->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: Does a QTreeView behave as you would expect, and it is only a problem with QTableView?  ( I take it you've already found this thread:    http://www.qtforum.org/article/13421/qtableview-how-to-make-rows-size-smaller.html )

Comment: yeah i saw it , maybe i need to set the Qt::SizeHintRole somewhere 
but the fact im subclassing QStyledItemDelegate and there is no data()
method to inherit there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint is useful only when QTableView::resizeRowsToContents, QTableView::resizeRowToContents, QTableView::resizeColumnsToContents and QTableView::resizeColumnToContents are called. or use

```
QHeaderView* headerView = tableView->horizontalHeader();
headerView->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: Is there any good documentation or information about this anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: **setColumnWidth** or **setRowHeight** and **horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed)** ?

Comment: how can i ? do i need to set each row size? its to much 
mybe im facing this bug ? 
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-20298?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

(*Credit where credit is due.*)
In @[HostileFork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211160/hostilefork)'s comment about a [Qt Forum discussion](http://www.qtforum.org/article/13421/qtableview-how-to-make-rows-size-smaller.html), there's a comment thread.  Within that thread, a user *mikhailt* offers a [good solution](http://www.qtforum.org/post/70086/qtableview-how-to-make-rows-size-smaller.html#post70086).

The *verticalHeader* has a *DefaultSectionSize* property that can be adjusted.  It doesn't matter whether the vertical header (labels on the left side of the table) is actually being displayed or not, the size will still be used.

```
ui->PList_tableView->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(34);
```

This just solved my problem with Qt 5.6, and saved me from adjusting each data row's height separately, or causing a resize on a table.

Based on the age of the comment thread where I found it, this was already working in Qt 4, too.