Getting the size of an item (QStyledItemDelegate?) in a QTableView in PyQt5?
In the example below (at end of the post), what I want to do, is to

have an image applied to a QTableView item (cell) if it has empty contents (as a DecorationRole, since I might have other logic which might use BackgroundRole)

this image should scale/resize according to the cell size


have a possibility to run a "resizeToContents" actions arbitrarily
start off the table with an "empty" state represented by a single empty cell

Now, with the code below, things generally work:

Image is applied to item (cell), if its data contents are empty - and it does scale with the cell (e.g. if we manually change column/row width/height)
"resizeToContents" generally works fine if the cell has data contents

The problem is with the starting "empty" state, the DecorationRole drawing, and resizeToContents - let me illustrate:

First, if the code below does not do the DecorationRole image for empty cells/items (self.do_decoration = False), then upon start we get this GUI state:

... and after clicking "resizeToContents", we get this GUI state instead:

... that is, the cell "shrinks" (gets its width reduced). However, on subsequent clicks on "resizeToContents", this second GUI state remains unchanged (constant).
However, if we do enable the DecorationRole image for empty cells/items (self.do_decoration = True), then the first GUI state after program start looks like this:

... and on every subsequent click on "resizeToContents", the cell/item grows - so after 5 clicks on "resizeToContents" the GUI state is like this:


The behavior I otherwise wanted (and expected) is: if a QTableView starts off with showing a single cell with empty data, and there are no changes to the cell data, then no matter how many times I click on "resizeToContents", I should have no change in the GUI state.

The fact that the GUI state changes in the "no DecorationRole" case at start is not a problem: I guess "resizeToContents" takes into account the contents of the labels "1" in the row and column headers as well, and resizes everything according to that - which can be solved by running "resizeToContents" once in init; then the user would see no change when "resizeToContents" is clicked after program start.
However, the constant growing of the cell size in the "yes DecorationRole" case is a problem; in my opinion, it is due to the fact that I cannot really get the size of the cell/item, since in a QTableView, the cells/items are not even QWidgets - they are QStyledItemDelegate, which have no methods to get or set item width or height. And therefore I have attempted a workaround in the code by using QTableView.rowHeight and QTableView.columnWidth - but these apparently return sizes that are slightly larger than the actual cell/item dimensions, and so the DecorationRole pixmap ends up slightly larger than the cell/item actual size - so next time "resizeToContents", it tries to accomodate this, but then a new, even larger, decoration pixmap is generated - and we end up in a sort of a recursive increase of cell size.
Which is why my question is ultimately - how do I get the actual size of a QStyledItemDelegate item (cell) in a QTableView? My guess is, if I could generate a pixmap with the actual size of the cell, then subsequent calls to "resizeToContents" would not increase the cell size anymore, and things would work as I had imagined them.
Here is the code:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPointF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QPalette, QPixmap, QBrush, QPen, QPainter)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStyleOptionViewItem, QStyledItemDelegate)
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parview):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._parview = parview # parent table view
        self.do_decoration = True
    #
    def create_pixmap(self, pic_qsize): # SO:62799632
        pixmap = QPixmap(pic_qsize)
        pixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0))
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        #painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue")))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#446600"), 4, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomLeft(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomRight(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topLeft(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,-4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topRight(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,-4))
        painter.end()
        return pixmap
    #
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if self.do_decoration and role == Qt.DecorationRole: # SO:74203503
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            if not(value):
                row_height = self._parview.rowHeight(index.row())        #-5
                column_width = self._parview.columnWidth(index.column()) #-13
                #item = self._parview.itemDelegate(index) # QStyledItemDelegate
                print(f"{row_height=} {column_width=}")
                pic_qsize = QSize(column_width, row_height)
                return self.create_pixmap(pic_qsize)
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralw = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralw)
        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralw)
        #
        self.btn = QPushButton("resizeToContents")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.resizeToContents)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        #
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        data = [ [ "" ] ]
        self.model = TableModel(data, self.table_view)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        #
    #
    def resizeToContents(self):
        self.table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table_view.resizeRowsToContents()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
window.resize(280, 140)
app.exec_()


First of all, generally speaking, the model should know absolutely nothing about its view(s) nor care about how its items are shown. What you're trying to do should almost always be done within a delegate, possibly using a custom item data role if you need to specify whether the "empty" image should be shown or not. The size increase you get is caused by the style considering the current contents of the item and eventually adjusting to its own margins, which is one more reasons for which the model should not care about those aspects, especially if they're considered for the decoration.

Thanks @musicamante - I'm still trying to get around the sort of thinking that goes into these kind model/view/delegate setups, so I was just trying to achieve the desired effect the best I could with the immediate knowledge I have. I will try to rework this using a custom delegate - I guess your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/79129869 will be a good starting point.

OK, thanks to the comment by @musicamante, I finally got to a solution.
The trick is basically to avoid creating and returning pixmaps based on QTableView cell/item size in TableModel.data(...) for Qt.DecorationRole (in this example, conditional on data for the cell/item being empty string) - and instead:

create a CustomItemDelegate class,
apply this class to the entire (all cells/items of) QTableView
and check for data empty for the cell/item in the CustomItemDelegate.paint(...) method - if the condition is a match, generate pixmap there, as .paint(...) has access to the .rect and thus the size of the cell / item - and then also, appropriately, paint the pixmap there as well.

With this, handling for Qt.DecorationRole in TableModel.data(...) is not needed anymore...
And, the behavior with these changes (code at end of post) is exactly the same as described in OP for "no DecorationRole": at program start, you get this GUI state: (I've added a BackgroundRole and one more cell with text, just to make sure painting is OK)

... and then when you click on "resizeToContents" for the first time after start, the GUI state changes to this:

... and after this, you can click to your heart's content on "resizeToContents", and the cell size will not change!
The corrected code:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPointF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QPalette, QPixmap, QBrush, QPen, QPainter)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStyleOptionViewItem, QStyledItemDelegate)
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class CustomItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/79129869
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        print(f"initStyleOption {opt.index=} {opt.text=} {opt.rect=} {opt.backgroundBrush=} {int(opt.features)=:#010b} {opt.decorationPosition=} {opt.decorationSize=}")
    #
    def create_pixmap(self, pic_qsize):       # https://stackoverflow.com/q/62799632
        pixmap = QPixmap(pic_qsize)
        pixmap.fill(QColor(0,0,0,0))
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        #painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue")))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#446600"), 4, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomLeft(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().bottomRight(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topLeft(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,-4))
        painter.drawLine(pixmap.rect().topRight(), pixmap.rect().center()+QPointF(0,-4))
        painter.end()
        return pixmap
    #
    def paint(self, painter, opt, index):     # https://stackoverflow.com/q/70487748
        # for paint, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/32032379
        # NOTE: opt.text is always "" here - options.text is actual cell/item text!
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(opt)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        print(f"paint {opt.text=} {options.text=} {opt.rect=} {options.rect=}")
        # super.paint has to run first, if we want the pixmap on top of the BackgroundRole
        super(CustomItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, options, index)
        if options.text == "":
            pixmap = self.create_pixmap(options.rect.size())
            painter.drawPixmap(options.rect, pixmap)
    #
    ## NOTE: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9782553
    ## > sizeHint is useful only when resizeRowsToContents, ...
    ## > ..., resizeColumnsToContents, ... are called
    def sizeHint(self, opt, index):           # https://stackoverflow.com/q/70487748
        # for sizeHint, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71358160
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(opt)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index) # options.text ...
        print(f"sizeHint {opt.rect=} {options.rect=}")
        return super(CustomItemDelegate, self).sizeHint(options, index)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parview):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._parview = parview # parent table view
    #
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:     # https://stackoverflow.com/q/57321588
            return QColor("#AAFF" + 2*str(index.column()*8))
        ## NO more need for DecorationRole for empty cell;
        ## CustomItemDelegate takes over that now!
        #if role == Qt.DecorationRole:    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/74203503
        #    value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        #    if not(value):
        #        row_height = self._parview.rowHeight(index.row())        #-5
        #        column_width = self._parview.columnWidth(index.column()) #-13
        #        #item = self._parview.itemDelegate(index) # QStyledItemDelegate
        #        print(f"{row_height=} {column_width=}")
        #        pic_qsize = QSize(column_width, row_height)
        #        return self.create_pixmap(pic_qsize)
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])


Creating a pixmap is completely pointless in this case: you already got a painter, use that and directly draw the lines in it. The other overrides are also unnecessary, as they do nothing useful in your code.

Thanks @musicamante - agreed on the other overrides, I left them just so I have a reference of what kind of overrides go there; but for the pixmap, I disagree that it is completely pointless - there is a pic_qsize argument, so that manual resize of the cell (via row or column resize) would trigger a redraw of a new pixmap that matches the new cell size.

The cells are always redrawn upon resizing, the fact that you use a pixmap is irrelevant, because the pixmap is then drawn again on the painter argument of paint(): you just need to set its pen and use the opt.rect as references for the four lines. Creating a pixmap for that is pointless and inefficient.
